# Would chess variant identity questions be on topic?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

On boardgamegeek someone thrifted a copy of a chess set that is unusual. Most of us cannot nail down what it is. To be fair it is possible it isn't even chess but it *really* looks like it could be one. I would be able to provide pictures and piece breakdowns.

Would a question like this on the main site be viable/on-topic?

If on topic I will make a proper question in main as to not distract the purpose of this meta question. If off-topic I will take it to chat although that looks to be not too busy.

Comment: Link to the BGG post if you dare: https://boardgamegeek.com/geeklist/276021/item/7825120#item7825120

Answer (score 2):

Since you have some doubts already if it's really a chess variant, I propose you ask this question on our sister site [Board & Card Games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/). They have an [[identify-this-game]](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-game) tag which is quite popular (and successful). And if does turn out to be a chess variant, well, they do not exclude [chess](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/tags/chess) from their scope.

Comment: One of the answers I expected. I will give it a shot over there. Wonder how many folks here are also on that stack.